# Are these two questions "similar"/"duplicates"?

Tags: support

I have two questions, posted by kalina. [Question 1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82063/is-it-possible-to-force-knifes-only-for-the-first-round), and [Question 2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/81997/is-it-possible-to-disable-certain-weapons-ie-awp).

Though the questions have different titles, they both specifically ask for something that can restrict weapons or limit weapons.  Are these two questions then considered the same?

I answered Question 2, using a mod I found at AlliedModders.  My answer for Question 2 however, also addresses Question 1, and in my opinion, the two are completely identical.

Are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say they are not duplicates.

While the common theme of weapon restrictions is present in both questions, the [former](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82063/is-it-possible-to-force-knifes-only-for-the-first-round) is more about placing round limits on said restrictions while the [latter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/81997/is-it-possible-to-disable-certain-weapons-ie-awp) is asking how to impose the restrictions altogether.

Could they have existed comfortably as one question?  Probably, but that does not mean we have to forcefully combine two distinct issues.

Comment: So is it perfectly okay for me to copy my original answer verbatim and post it on the other question?

Comment: @Retrosaur If the same answer applies, sure.  There is nothing wrong with having one answer apply to two questions.

Answer (score 1):

## Nope.

We don't dupe posts based on the answers.  The mod you linked to can probably be used to solve both questions, but that doesn't change the fact that *what is being asked* in one of them is in no way related to what is being asked in the other.

Comment: I might have minced my words. @gnomeslice I meant the questions are actually extremely similar in nature.  If I were to ask a question, saying "how can I make CSGo rounds Grenades only", would that question be considered similar to kalina's other questions due to the fact that it pertains to weapon restrictions?

Comment: 'Weapons Restrictions' is a really vague topic; both of those deal with it, yes, but that's like saying that two people are duplicates because they both have green eyes.  Or something.

Comment: They both deal with the same problem, restricting certain weapons during gameplay (Question 1 deals with Knives only, Question 2 deals with no AWPs).

Comment: I still think the use cases are different enough that they should be kept separate.

Comment: By 'in no way related' I actually meant 'related'.